# "SEVERE: Error starting static Resources " in catalina.log

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat6

I am getting the following Exception in Catalina.log file when I try to start tomcat 6.
I looked for similar queries but could not find a solution mentioned to it.Please note that I have my app inside the tomcat webapp and I am not using eclipse to run it.

```
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: ............
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9090
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 390 ms
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\host-manager does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4048)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/host-manager] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager] has not been started
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\manager does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4048)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/manager] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] has not been started
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\MyAPP\WEB-INF\lib\servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:47 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9090
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:47 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:9009
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:47 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Jun 14, 2012 12:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2409 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1) Make sure Tomcat isn't inadvertantly deleting your .war.  This can happen if something about the .war is "broken":

http://www.coderanch.com/t/479329/Tomcat/disappearing-war-file-tomcat

2) Don't use filenames with spaces.

You can use "dir/x" from a command prompt to see the DOS "8.3" name of any Windows directory:

EXAMPLE: `"c:\Program files"` likely has the "short name" `"C:\PROGRA~1"`

3) Edit your descriptors (including app.xml) to substitute the 8.3 name for anything with spaces in it.

4) Unless you're sure Tomcat itself is OK (for example, does the default Tomcat page appear?), then you might just want to consider deleting and reinstalling it.

'Hope that helps